# ASP.NET Website Server error '/' being thrown

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am currently working with SQL queries on an ASP.NET empty website (Visual Studio). The first time I ran the build, everything worked fine. It displayed all required records with no problem.

However, after changing the SQL command, it now throws an error at build-time, and I cannot figure out why:

To be clear, I first configured the data source:

[image]

And then added a WHERE clause:
[image]

and now I am left with this error each time:
[image]

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Well the error seems straightforward. You're trying to wire up an event handler, but it can't find the handler you've indicated. You should show your event handler from the code behind. Your error itself has nothing to do with SQL or Visual Studio, so I'm removing those tags. And since you're in the Web Forms framework, I'm adding that tag. Always remember to tag your question with the relevant framework.

Comment: If you're learning ASP.NET for the first time, why did you choose Web Forms?!

Comment: @mason To be honest, I do not know

Comment: You should put a little more thought into what you choose to learn. Web Forms is dying, it's hard to work with, it's slow etc. If you want to learn ASP.NET, then you should either explore ASP.NET MVC Core or ASP.NET Web API + <JavaScript front-end framework>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `OnSelecting="SQlPracticeSource_Selecting"` from your aspx page and run again